# Error when deleting object from Core Data managet Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios6, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My app uses a Core Data managed Table View on which I've implemented with the help of some good folks at cimgf.com a method for re-ordering content.
Before doing so, I was able to delete objects easily by using the code below:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [self.tableView beginUpdates]; // Avoid  NSInternalInconsistencyException

        // Delete the person object that was swiped
        Step *stepToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"Deleting (%@)", stepToDelete.name);
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:stepToDelete];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

        // Delete the (now empty) row on the table
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self performFetch];

        [self.tableView endUpdates];

        [delegate stepChangedOnMaster:self];
    }
}
```

After adding the code below, when an object is deleted, the app crashes.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath;
{
    NSMutableArray *things = [[__fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];

    // Grab the item we're moving.
    NSManagedObject *thing = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];

    // Remove the object we're moving from the array.
    [things removeObject:thing];

    // Now re-insert it at the destination.
    [things insertObject:thing atIndex:[destinationIndexPath row]];

    // All of the objects are now in their correct order. Update each
    // object's displayOrder field by iterating through the array.
    int i = 0;
    for (NSManagedObject *mo in things)
    {
        NSLog(@"%i - %@", i, [mo valueForKey:@"name"]);
        [mo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i++] forKey:@"displayOrder"];
    }
    things = nil;
    [__managedObjectContext save:nil];
    // Save
      NSError *error = nil;
    if (![__managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
        NSString *msg = @"An error occurred when attempting to save your user profile changes.\nThe application needs to quit.";
        NSString *details = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %s: %@", [self class], _cmd, [error userInfo]];
        NSLog(@"%@\n\nDetails: %@", msg, details);
    }

    // re-do the fetch so that the underlying cache of objects will be sorted
    // correctly
    NSError *errror = nil;
    if (![__fetchedResultsController performFetch:&errror])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", errror, [errror userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I really don't understand why the app crashes. Can someone give me some tips on how to fix this? Thank you!

This is the error I get:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 2 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
*

Comment: What does the debug console provide about the crash? There should be some sort of message or so. If you set an exception breakpoint then you may have to press "coninue" one or two times before the error message is displayed.

Comment: updated the question with the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you call `deleteRowsAtIndexPath` you need to sync your model data to correspond to the number of items you will have in the table view after the deletion operation, which is n-1 in your case. Although you delete it from your persistent store, the item is probably still cached in the array which count you return in table view's number of rows for section method.